# How to maintain the order of elements of a row when using by and rbind function in r?

Tags: r, function, sorting, outliers, rbind

I have written a function which takes a subset of data based on the value of name column.It Computes the outlier for column "mark" and replaces all the outliers.
However when I try to combine these different subsets, the order of my elements changes. Is there any way by which I can maintain the order of my elements in the column "mark"

My data set is:

```
 name   mark  
    A  100.0   
    B  0.5   
    C  100.0  
    A  50.0   
    B  90.0   
    B  1000.0   
    C  1200.0   
    C  5000.0   
    A  210.0
```

The function which I have written is :

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", as.list(by(data, data$name, 
   function(x){apply(x[, .(mark)],2, 
   function(y) {y[y > (quantile(x$mark, na.rm=TRUE)[[3]][[1]] + 1.5 * IQR(x$mark))] 
   <- (quantile(x$mark, na.rm=TRUE)[[3]][[1]] + 1.5 * IQR(x$mark));y})}))))
```

The result of the above function is the first column below (I've manually added back `name` for illustratory purposes):

```
      mark      NAME
100.000 ----- A
50.000 ----- A
210.000 ----- A
0.500 ----- B
90.000 ----- B
839.625 ----- B
100.000 ----- C
1200.000 ----- C
4875.000 ----- C
```

In the above result, the order of the values for mark column are changed. Is there any way by which I can maintain the order of the elements ?

Comment: Why do you need the `apply` within?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that code is doing what you think it is?

It looks like you're replacing any value greater than the median (third returned value of `quantile`) with the median + 1.5*IQR. Maybe that's what you intend, I don't know. The bigger problem is that you're doing that in an `apply` function, so it's going to re-calculate that median and IQR each iteration, updated with the previous rows already being changed. I'd wager that's not what you intend, but I suppose I've seen stranger.

A better option might be to create an external function to do the work, which takes in all of the data, does the calculation, then outputs all the data. I like `dplyr` for this simply because it's clean.

Reading your data in (why the "----"?)

```
scores <- read.table(text="
name   mark  
A 100.0   
B 0.5   
C 100.0  
A 50.0   
B 90.0   
B 1000.0   
C 1200.0   
C 5000.0   
A 210.0", header=TRUE)
```

and creating a function that does something a little more sensible; replaces any value greater than the 75% quantile (referenced by name so you know what it is)  or less than the 25% quantile with that limiting value

```
scale_outliers <- function(data) {

  lim <- quantile(data, na.rm = TRUE)
  data[data > lim["75%"]] <- lim["75%"]
  data[data < lim["25%"]] <- lim["25%"]
  return(data)

}
```

Chaining this processing into `dplyr::mutate` is neat, and can then be passed on to `ggplot`. Here's the original data

```
gg1 <- scores %>% ggplot(aes(x=name, y=mark)) 
gg1 <- gg1 + geom_point() + geom_boxplot() + coord_cartesian(ylim=range(scores$mark))
gg1
```

[image: gg1]

And if we alter it with the new function we get the data back without rows changed around

```
scores %>% mutate(new_mark = scale_outliers(mark))
#>   name   mark new_mark
#> 1    A  100.0      100
#> 2    B    0.5       90
#> 3    C  100.0      100
#> 4    A   50.0       90
#> 5    B   90.0       90
#> 6    B 1000.0     1000
#> 7    C 1200.0     1000
#> 8    C 5000.0     1000
#> 9    A  210.0      210
```

and we can plot that,

```
gg2 <- scores %>% mutate(new_mark = scale_outliers(mark)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=name, y=new_mark)) 
gg2 <- gg2 + geom_point() + geom_boxplot()  + coord_cartesian(ylim=range(scores$mark))
gg2
```

[image: gg2]

Best of all, if you now want to do that quantile comparison group-wise (say, by the `name` column, it's as easy as using `dplyr::group_by(name)`,

```
gg3 <- scores %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(new_mark = scale_outliers(mark)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=name, y=new_mark)) 
gg3 <- gg3 + geom_point() + geom_boxplot()  + coord_cartesian(ylim=range(scores$mark))
gg3
```

[image: gg3]

Answer (score 0):

A slightly refactored version of Hack-R's answer -- you can add a index to your `data.table`:

```
data <- data.table(name = c("A", "B","C", "A","B","B","C","C","A"),mark = c(100,0.5,100,50,90,1000,1200,5000,210))
data[,i:=.I]
```

Then you perform your calculation but you keep the `name` and `i`:

```
df <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", as.list(
    by(data, data$name,
       function(x) cbind(i=x$i, 
                     name=x$name,
                     apply(x[, .(mark)], 2,function(y) {y[y > (quantile(x$mark, na.rm=TRUE)[[3]][[1]] + 1.5 * IQR(x$mark))] <- (quantile(x$mark, na.rm=TRUE)[[3]][[1]] + 1.5 * IQR(x$mark));y})
                     )))))
```

And finally you order using the index:

```
df[order(df$i),]
  i name    mark
1 1    A     100
4 2    B     0.5
7 3    C     100
2 4    A      50
5 5    B      90
6 6    B 839.625
8 7    C    1200
9 8    C    4875
3 9    A     210
```